# Inverter circuit (DC to AC)

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, capacitor, current

[image]

Hi readers, above is an inverter circuit that converts DC to AC. How do I increase the output voltage and decrease the frequency to let’s say 60 Hz?

[image]

Above pic is the voltage I measured at AC (Vout).

Comment: Do you understand the purpose of the transformer in your schematic? Did you learn how transformers work? (This was a problem in your previous questions.) Do you really have only 10 turns on the primary? Why? Where did the design come from? What is the battery voltage when you measure that output?

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You may have better luck with a circuit like this one. You’ll have to adjust a couple values and maybe use a different transformer to get the right frequency and voltage but the tutorial walks you through this. https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/100-watt-inverter-circuit

Answer (score 2):

Your output is short-curcuited. Increase R3 or reduce R1 and R2.

Answer (score 0):

You increase the output voltage by changing the coil ratio (your L1, L2, L3). Largest coil ratio = largest voltage at the output. (Make L1, L2 smaller but keep them at the same value and L3 larger)

Regarding the frequency, this changes by changing the frequency you tun on/off the transistors.